# use reactJS with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, model-view-controller

I need to design a huge client side application by following MVC architecture.
As of I know angular is best for developing a SPA by in mvc architecture.

I'm not familiar with ReactJS, when i'm going through ReactJS i came to know that ReactJS is best creating user interfaces and building reusable components.

link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/why-react.html says **React as the V in MVC.**

From that my question is:

1. **is it possible to use both angularJS (framework) & reactJS(library) in same SPA.**
2. **is it possible to create Views using ReactJS and other part of my application in angularjs (M & C part in MVC).**

Comment: What will be the technology using for the backend side ?

Comment: It depends on your scenario and stuffs

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, React in itself as a smaller scope than Angular, it is not a so-called "framework" but it's a library used to render views, or components inside a view. You will have to assemble many other libraries around React to get a full SPA application, however the good news is that skilled developers already picked them for you and pulled out very useful boiler plates that should get you started much much faster than if you were to do all the work by yourself.

Take a look at those:

[Find your perfect React starter project](http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project/)

[react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

[react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)

I based my latest app on the 3rd one and I love it, but it's personal ...

Now your questions:

1. Yes you can use both, take a look at [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact), let's you run React components in an Angular app. If you start from scratch however and don't have legacy code or libs written in one of the two technologies, my recommendation would be to either use one or the other. This kind of hybrid solution would let you slowly migrate an Angular app to React by rewritting one by one your components without breaking the whole app at once.
2. That's pretty much what I said in 1/ this can be done but if I were to write the app from scratch I would pick either Angular or React depending on time constraints, existing code base and willingness to learn a new framework. My recommendation: take a few days to experience various boilerplates and pick the one that you feel the most comfortable with...

Answer (score 0):

We can acheive this with **Microfrontends** and  webpack5 [ModuleFederationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/).

**MicroFrontends**: architectural approach to develop frontend applications by decomposing them into smaller, independently deployable modules

**ModuleFederationPlugin**: Module federation allow us to a build to provide or consume modules with other independent builds at runtime.

These independent build can be developed in any UI library or framework and consume in applcation.